# Google App Engine internal network

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to route HTTP traffic between google app engine applications without going through the public internet?

For example, if I'm running a Web Service API on one application and want to build a second application on top of it without traffic going through the internet - for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Between separate apps running on different domains? I suspect not.

But you can use backends to do different work behind the scenes:

> Backends are special App Engine instances that have no request deadlines, higher memory and CPU limits, and persistent state across requests. They are started automatically by App Engine and can run continously for long periods. Each backend instance has a unique URL to use for requests, and you can load-balance requests across multiple instances.

When I look at the logs between the backend and the front end instances I see IPs like

> 0.1.0.3

So yes, those communication paths are internal. I'd hazard a *guess* that as so much of the internet *is* google you could say requests between different apps might not travel on the public internet.

Logs indicate low latency communication between front and back ends, not under any particular load however. Your milage may vary.

[Backends in Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/)